# Animation for Toast messages in Android

Tags: android, animation, toast

I would like to ask if it is possible to have animated toast messages for Android. For example,after the successful registration of a user,a toast message appears from the top and goes away after 2 seconds. I strongly believe that those small details make an app to look great.

Comment: you will need to make your own custom view for that then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's not possible to make a custom toast animation, with the stock Android toast class.**

> Stock style toasts (ones added to the WindowManager and not to a
>   ViewGroup) are limited to four system animations and will not accept
>   animations from your project.

**So the only way to implement animation or a custom Toast message** is to create your own custom Toast class, or use some library such as this one  [SuperToasts library](https://github.com/JohnPersano/SuperToasts)

Comment: Thanks for sir. That library is really cool.

Answer (score 0):

toast appear from top and after some time disappear for this kind of functionality is not include in android, you must use third party library Crounton.Using Crounton this kind of functionality implement.

https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton

Here is the link of library and you find some samples in library also.